# Is “vigésimo tercera” considered an acceptable alternative to “vigésima tercera”?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, número-gramatical, concordancia-gramatical

**Primero mi pregunta en español:**

¿Se considera “vigésimo tercera” una alternativa aceptable a “vigésima tercera”?

**Details in English:**

When I first started using ordinal numbers past 20, I learned that they involve a two-word construction.  For example, to say "twenty-third edition," I would need to write:

**vigésima tercera edición**

but then I came across an article in *El País* with the following:

> **No parece que vaya a ocurrir con la versión vigésimo tercera, ...**
>
> —*From [**"Menos sexismo en el nuevo Diccionario"**](https://elpais.com/cultura/2013/11/24/actualidad/1385324034_063421.html)*

At first I thought it might just be a typo, but wanting to be sure, I decided to run it through Google's Ngram, which showed me this:

[image]

As you can see from the images above, I also tried “trigésimo/trigésima” with “tercera,” and clearly, there appears to be evidence that both are used.

So, to repeat my question, is “vigésimo tercera” considered an acceptable alternative to “vigésima tercera” or does something else explain what appears to be a rather prevalent use of it?  Is there a name for a phrase/construct like this and are there other examples of it in Spanish?  (If these last couple of questions seem to be straying from the topic a bit, but you’ve got an answer, I can post them in a separate question, if necessary.)

**Detalles en español:**

Cuando empecé a usar números ordinales más allá de 20, aprendí que suponen una construcción de dos palabras.  Por ejemplo, para decir "twenty-third edition" necesitaría escribir

**vigésima tercera edición**

pero luego, me encontré con un artículo en *El País* con lo siguiente:

> **No parece que vaya a ocurrir con la versión vigésimo tercera, ...**
>
> —*De [**"Menos sexismo en el nuevo Diccionario"**](https://elpais.com/cultura/2013/11/24/actualidad/1385324034_063421.html)*

Al principio, creí que podría ser un error tipográfico, pero, para estar segura, decidí pasarlo por el Ngram Viewer de Google, que me mostró esto:

[Véase la imágenes de arriba.]

Como puede verse en la imagen de arriba, también probé con “trigésimo/trigésima” y “tercera” y, claramente, parece que hay evidencia de que se utilizan ambas expresiones.

Entonces, para repetir mi pregunta, ¿se considera “vigésimo tercera” una alternativa aceptable de “vigésima tercera”? ¿O puede haber otra explicación del uso, en apariencia bastante predominante, de aquella?  ¿Tienen un nombre las expresiones /construcciones como esta?  Y, ¿hay otros ejemplos de ella en español?  (Si este último par de preguntas se apartan un poco del tema pero alguien tiene una respuesta, puedo ponerlas en otra pregunta, si fuera necesario.)

Comment: See related Meta question: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2821/9385

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's either *vigésima tercera* or *vigesimotercera*. That is, you either

- write the two parts separately, keeping the written accent mark and the gender agreement on both as applicable, or
- write the two parts as one word, keeping the accent and the gender of the last part only.

For numbers 30 and on, only the former alternative is acceptable (i.e. you cannot write **trigesimoprimera* but only *trigésima primera*).

This is according to the *[Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=ordinales)*:

> De los ordinales compuestos, los correspondientes a la primera y a la segunda decena se pueden escribir en una o en dos palabras, siendo
>   hoy mayoritaria la grafía simple (*decimotercero, decimocuarto,
>   vigesimoprimero, vigesimoctavo*, etc.). A partir de la tercera decena
>   solo se emplean las grafías complejas (*trigésimo primero,
>   cuadragésimo segundo, quincuagésimo tercero*, etc.). Si el ordinal se
>   escribe en dos palabras, el primer elemento mantiene la tilde que le
>   corresponde como palabra independiente: *vigésimo segundo*; pero si se
>   escribe en una sola palabra, el ordinal no debe llevar tilde, pues no
>   le corresponde llevarla según las reglas de acentuación:
>   *vigesimosegundo* (no *vigésimosegundo*). **Los ordinales compuestos escritos en una sola palabra solo presentan variación de género y
>   número en el segundo componente: *vigesimoprimera, vigesimoprimeros,
>   vigesimoprimeras*; pero si se escriben en dos palabras, ambos
>   componentes son variables: *vigésima primera, vigésimos primeros,
>   vigésimas primeras*.**

Of course, as you can see, actual usage often departs from the rule.

Comment: I think you meant "the former alternative" not "latter"?

Comment: @pablodf76 Both answers here were really good, but since yours is written both in English and Spanish, and will therefore be more beneficial to a wider audience — those who are Spanish-English bilingual or semi-bilingual and those who are not or who are farther away from that end of the spectrum — you will receive the green checkmark.  I especially like the fact that you addressed the Ngram by stating that usage often departs from the rule.  That helps quell any notions that the less common usage is considered acceptable (outside of common/daily/colloquial usage).

Answer (score 5):

Según el [artículo del DPD para los ordinales](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=ordinales), los ordinales cualifican al sustantivo, es decir que son adjetivos y por tanto deben concordar en género con el sustantivo.

El ordinal para el número 20 (masculino, femenino) es *vigésim**o**, vigésim**a***; y el ordinal para el número 3 es *tercer**o**, tercer**a***. Hasta aquí todo bien.

Los ordinales del 11º al 29º se pueden escribir de dos maneras: juntos, o separados.

- Cuando se escriben separados, ambos deben concordar en género con el sustantivo; y así, el ordinal para el número 23 es *vigésim**o** tercer**o*** en masculino, *vigésim**a** tercer**a*** en femenino.
- Cuando se escriben juntos, el primero de ellos se convierte en una especie de prefijo, y se libra de concordar en género: y así, según el DPD, también es válido *vigesim**o**tercer**o*** en masculino, *vigesim**o**tercer**a*** en femenino.

A partir del número 30 y en adelante, esta regla ya no aplica, y todos los elementos se escriben separados y en concordancia: el ordinal para el número 35 debe ser forzosamente *trigésim**o** quint**o*** en masculino, *trigésim**a** quint**a*** en femenino.

Y ahora, respondiendo a tu petición de *"explicar lo que parece ser un uso bastante predominante"*...

**El problema es que, al hablar, es casi imposible diferenciar "*vigesimotercera*" de** Ⓧ**"*vigésimo tercera*".** Y puesto que decir *vigesimotercera* es correcto, y que lo normal es escribir los ordinales separados (sólo se escriben juntos del 11º al 29º, recordemos), es habitual cometer el error de transcribir *vigesimotercera* como dos palabras separadas, Ⓧ*vigésimo tercera*.

Es un error tan común, de hecho, que mi intuición es que en algún momento futuro se aceptará el uso de "vigésimo tercera" así, separado.

Comment: Es posible diferenciar *vigésimo tercera* y *vigesimotercera*, aunque la diferencia es sutil. En la primera, hay dos sílabas tónicas. En la segunda, apenas hay una. Es la misma diferencia que hay entre *dieciséis* ( ˘ ˘ ´ ) y *diez y seis* ( ´ ˘ ´ ) y básicamente la de entre *veinte y nueve* ( ´ ˘ [˘] ˘ ´ ˘ ) y *veintinueve* ( ˘ ˘ ´ ˘ )

Comment: @walen Tu comentario sobre lo que se usa en discurso cotidiano es definitivamente un aspecto que no había considerado así que gracias por eso.  Para que conste, sin embargo, el Ngram muestra tendencias de la palabra escrita como se encuentra en libros.